# How to repeat MySQL query for multiple intervals

Tags: mysql

I've got a query which produces the proper results for a given time interval of 15 minutes.

```
-- Query for the interval 10:00-10:15
SELECT count(r.id) as nof_reservations_in_interval
FROM reservations r
LEFT JOIN assets a ON r.asset_id = a.id
WHERE r.deleted_at is null
AND a.type_id = 23 --just an ID
AND r.start_utc <= '2017-02-21 10:15:00'
AND r.end_utc >= '2017-02-21 10:00:00'
-- result: 2
```

If I want to make a 'table/relation' with the results for this query between, lets say, 10:00 and 18:00 on the same day. How could I achieve that?

I could just query the statement from php for every interval; but I hoped there was some kind of smart MySQL function to do this :)

Desired result relation:

```
interval_start | interval_end | nof_reservations_in_interval
---------------+--------------+------------------------------
10:00          | 10:15        | 2
10:15          | 10:30        | 3
etc etc
```

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to define the intervals using a subquery:

```
SELECT t.time_start, t.time_end, count(r.id) as nof_reservations_in_interval
FROM (SELECT time('10:10:00') as time_start, time('10:15:00') as time_end UNION ALL
      SELECT time('10:15:00') as time_start, time('10:30:00') as time_end  
     ) t LEFT JOIN
     reservations r
     ON r.start_utc <= addtime('2017-02-21', t.time_end) AND
        r.end_utc >= addtime('2017-02-21', t.time_start) LEFT JOIN
     assets a
     ON r.asset_id = a.id AND
         a.type_id = 23
WHERE r.deleted_at is null 
GROUP BY t.time_start, t.time_end;
```

Note:  I moved the condition on `a.type_id` to the `on` clause for the `left join`s to work.

Comment: Nice! But then I'll need to 'manually' enter every interval between 10:00 and 18:00 to produce the correct table.

Comment: And it looks like its not producing the right results; as I know there are 2 reservations in 10:00-10:15; but the query returns 0. (Even after fixing the 10:10 typo :)

Comment: Looks like the addtime is not functioning properly. Changing it to concat() works. But still looks cumbersome to manually enter all the possible intervals.